# Boo: Explicitly specifying the type of a hash

Tags: hash, boo, static-typing

I am new to Boo, and trying to figure out how to declare the type of a hash. When I do:

```
   myHash = {}
   myHash[key] = value
   (later)
   myHash[key].method()
```

the compiler complains that "method is not a member of object". I gather that it doesn't know what type the value in the hash is.

Is there any way I can declare to the compiler what type the keys and values of the hash are so that it won't complain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The builtin hashtable in boo is very similar to the standard .NET Hashtable - the key and value of each entry are both of type "object".

Your best bet is to use a generic Dictionary:

```
import System.Collections.Generic

myHash = Dictionary[of string, Foo]()
```

This example will create a dictionary where the type of the key is a string, and the value will be of type Foo

Answer (score 1):

Another option that leaves your code unchanged is to enable duck typing with the `-ducky` switch. I personally exclusively use the collections from `System.Collections.Generic` instead of the built-in list and dictionary types, as performance is much better.